# how to share image on facebooke/whatsapp/instagram fron ios xcode app

Tags: objective-c

I have images and videos and text on table view and also having share button 
want to click on share button then how to open social icons and how to share on instagram /whatsapp/facebook/twitter media 
i am using xcode 8 with ios 10 and objective c
any body can help me please

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Facebook and Instagram Without any integration
selectedIndexCollectionCells is array containing image to be shared
Else for multiple sharing on Facebook you can use integration (Photos Framework used)

```
 - (IBAction)shareButtonAction:(id)sender {
        if ([selectedIndexCollectionCells count] > 1){
            UIAlertController *alert1 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Share!" message:@"Please Select only 1 Image to share" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *firstAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
            [alert1 addAction:firstAction];
            [self presentViewController:alert1 animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
       else if ([selectedIndexCollectionCells count] != 0 ) {
            UIAlertController *alert1 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Social Media Platforms" message:@"Where Would you Like to Share" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *firstAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Instagram" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                [self savePostsPhotoBeforeSharing];
            }];
            UIAlertAction *secondAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Facebook" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                SLComposeViewController *controllerSLC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
                [controllerSLC setInitialText:@""];
                [controllerSLC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
                [controllerSLC addImage:choosenImage];
                [self presentViewController:controllerSLC animated:YES completion:Nil];
            }];
            UIAlertAction *ThirdAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
            [alert1 addAction:firstAction];
            [alert1 addAction:secondAction];
            [alert1 addAction:ThirdAction];
            [self presentViewController:alert1 animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else {
            UIAlertController *alert1 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Share!" message:@"Please Select Image To Share" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *firstAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];        
            [alert1 addAction:firstAction];
            [self presentViewController:alert1 animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }


-(void)savePostsPhotoBeforeSharing {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(choosenImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);
}
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo; {
    [self sharePostOnInstagram];
}
-(void)sharePostOnInstagram
{
    PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO],];
    __block PHAsset *assetToShare;
    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:fetchOptions];
    [result enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset *asset, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        assetToShare = asset;
    }];

    if([assetToShare isKindOfClass:[PHAsset class]])
    {
        NSString *localIdentifier = assetToShare.localIdentifier;
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=%@",localIdentifier];
        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: instagramURL]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: instagramURL];
        } else {
            UIAlertController *removedSuccessFullyAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error!!" message:@"No Instagram Application Found!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction *firstAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Okay" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
            [removedSuccessFullyAlert addAction:firstAction];
            [self presentViewController:removedSuccessFullyAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
}
```